# Type or Reference missing. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
 public static ModbusMasterSerial mm;
```

> I'm Getting Error : the type or namespace name 'ModbusMasterSerial' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have already added reference of Modbus in reference section. and I'm using that by adding  `using Modbus`to my code. but still getting the same error.can you tell which is appropriate reference for ModbusMasterSerial?

Comment: Do you have the using directive?

Comment: add usinig [namespace] click the error than {ALT} + {.} and you get the list of options to fix this choose the first

Comment: You probably have a typo.  Verify the variable is typed correctly.  The other reason for issue is the variable is defined in a different section of the code.

Comment: You say you added the reference by adding a using. But you also need to add the assembly (possibly a dll) und references in the project explorer. Additionally, you need to add the using in every file you want to access types from the assembly.

Comment: Reference and using is 2 differente thing. Ref are like the book you have in on your shell. Using is link to page of those book. You can't expect a link to book that you don't have to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate using directive for ModbusMasterSerial.

click on the ModbusMasterSerial.And type ctrl + .  It will show you some options.Add appropriate namespace from there.

Comment: can you tell me which is appropriate directive for ModbusMasterSerial as I'm new to c#.